# CSS select every em element first-child of a paragraph in even position

Tags: css, css-selectors

I have to apply red background to all elements `<EM>` first child of paragraphs in even position. Could you help me?

I  tried:

```
p:nth-child(even)>em:first-child{background-color:red;}
```

But it doesn't work..

Comment: `first-child` and `background-color`. Try fixing the spelling. ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
p:nth-child(even) em{ font-weight: bold; background: red; }
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/moonspace/uj6jwwo5/1/

Comment: @Filomena Del Sorbo: If what you tried didn't work, then either your first em isn't the first child, or it is the first child of some other element within the paragraph. If your paragraphs will only have at most one em, then this will work, otherwise it may match too many em elements (i.e. all of them).

Comment: p:nth-child(even) em:first-child{ font-weight: bold; background: red; } - will solve multiple ems.

Answer (score 0):

Change like this:

```
p:nth-child(even)>em:nth-child(1){background-colour:red;}
```

or this:

```
p:nth-child(even)>em:first-child{background-colour:red;}
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/teqt0rxt/).

Answer (score 0):

This code should do what you want.

```
<p><em>first</em> <em>dasdas</em></p>
<p><em>first</em> <em>dasdas</em></p>
<p><em>first</em> <em>dasdas</em></p>
<p><em>first</em> <em>dasdas</em></p>
<p><em>first</em> <em>dasdas</em></p>
<p><em>first</em> <em>dasdas</em></p>
<p><em>first</em> <em>dasdas</em></p>

p:nth-child(even) > em:first-child{ background-color: red;}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/y5938zqm/1/

You had there a few typos:

- `firstichild` instead of `first-child`
- `background-colour` instead of `background-color` (without `u` in color)